# Sign and encrypt a file

Tags: python

I have 2 files called digit.pem and sign.pem. Both have the same password xxxx.

I need that myfile.zip to become myfile.p7m after applying the sign.pem file and .enc after applying the digit.pem file .

In openssl the command is this:

```
openssl smime -sign –in DATA/myfile.zip –outform der –binary –nodetach -out DATA/myfile.p7m -signer CERTS/sign.pem -passin pass:xxxx

openssl smime -sign –in DATA/myfile.p7m –outform der –binary –nodetach -out DATA/myfile.enc -signer CERTS/digit.pem -passin pass:xxxx
```

This is an example about the structure of pem file.

```
Bag Attributes
friendlyName:
localKeyID:
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
friendlyName:
localKeyID:
subject=C
issuer=
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to know how can I use this .pem file in a Python Program.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know how can I use this .pem file in a Python Program.

Comment: Use how? To do what?

Comment: I need that myfile.zip to become myfile.p7m after applying the digit.pem and sign.pem files.

Comment: Your example openssl command doesn't reference any of digit.pem, sign.pem, myfile.zip, or myfile.p7m.

Comment: What doeas mean that "my file... to become"? How do you "apply" digit.pem and sign.pem?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command you posted on a shell via python using [multiprocessing.run()](http://You%20can%20run%20the%20command%20you%20posted%20on%20a%20shell%20via%20python%20using%20%60multiprocessing.run()%60.%20Read%20the%20docs%20at%20https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.run).

```
from multiprocessing import run

cmd = 'openssl smime -sign –in DATA/dati –outform der –binary –nodetach -out DATA/dati.p7m -signer CERTS/FIRMA.PEM -passin pass:xxxx'

run(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please specify the inputs and the desired output. Give some context. It's really hard to understand what is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have to sign and crypt a file with 2 .PEM certificates. the first .pem file must produce me, once applied to the zip file, a p7m file, after the second .pem file you must get me an .enc file. My problem is that i'm new on python so i don't have an example code

Comment: Python has nothing to do with it. Can you do it via opessl? If so you can use python to call openssl (as in my answer). Or you can use a library that wrap openssl like https://www.pyopenssl.org .